# Cause of neo4j IndexOutOfBoundsException on getRelationships()

Tags: neo4j

This is happening in `neo4j` version `2.3.0-M02`

Why might this code ....

```
Iterable<Relationship> rels = node.getRelationships( ... any various args ... );
for (Relationship rel : rels) {
    // Some computation
}
```

... cause this stack trace ?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCursor.setOffset(MuninnPageCursor.java:410)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.RelationshipGroupStore.getRecord(RelationshipGroupStore.java:117)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.RelationshipGroupStore.getRecord(RelationshipGroupStore.java:77)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.StoreRelationshipIterable$DenseIterator.<init>(StoreRelationshipIterable.java:214)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.StoreRelationshipIterable.iterator(StoreRelationshipIterable.java:96)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.StoreRelationshipIterable.iterator(StoreRelationshipIterable.java:76)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.store.DiskLayer.nodeListRelationships(DiskLayer.java:241)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.store.CacheLayer.nodeListRelationships(CacheLayer.java:424)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.StateHandlingStatementOperations.nodeGetRelationships(StateHandlingStatementOperations.java:925)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.StateHandlingStatementOperations.nodeGetRelationships(StateHandlingStatementOperations.java:933)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.nodeGetRelationships(ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.java:426)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.OperationsFacade.nodeGetRelationships(OperationsFacade.java:361)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy$2.iterator(NodeProxy.java:194)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy$2.iterator(NodeProxy.java:186)
```

---

Update:

- [Issue #5691 on Github](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/5691)
- [Same bug again in version `2.3.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351632/cause-of-neo4j-indexoutofboundsexception-on-getrelationships-again)

Comment: can you add a simple `system.out.println("DEBUG");` in your for loop? to see if it does this at least one time. The problem might come from an empty result set

Comment: It does not actually enter the loop ...

Comment: You should definitely upgrade your code to 2.3.0-M03. Milestone releases are not stable - bug may occur. So, upgrade Neo4j and check - maybe bug is fixed and there are no exception anymore.

Comment: In addition to what @FylmTM said, I suggest running consistency checker on your store directory, for details see http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/01/22/neo4j-backup-store-copy-and-consistency-check/

Comment: @FylmTM Upgrading to the next milestone appears to have fixed this. If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade to Neo4j 2.3.0-M03.

Milestone releases tend to be unstable and you are using old one. It is known that M02 has bugs, and lot of them are fixed in M03.

So, upgrade and check if this works for you.