# Cause of neo4j IndexOutOfBoundsException on getRelationships() [Again]

Tags: neo4j

This question is a duplicate of [Cause of neo4j IndexOutOfBoundsException on getRelationships()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846687/cause-of-neo4j-indexoutofboundsexception-on-getrelationships) **except** for one important point:

- In that question the version of `neo4j` was `2.3.0-M02` - the fix was to upgrade to `2.3.0-M03`
- That fix worked, and now, after also testing with `2.3.0-RC1`, the same error is back again, only now with the full release `2.3.0`.

I have trouble believing a Release has a bug which the Release
   Candidate and final Milestone did not, yet which one of the earlier Milestones did.

So, to be clear, I am using Neo4j Release `2.3.0` and getting the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCursor.setOffset(MuninnPageCursor.java:419)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.RelationshipGroupStore.readRecord(RelationshipGroupStore.java:143)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.RelationshipGroupStore.forceGetRecord(RelationshipGroupStore.java:106)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.store.StoreNodeRelationshipCursor.init(StoreNodeRelationshipCursor.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.store.StoreAbstractNodeCursor.relationships(StoreAbstractNodeCursor.java:203)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.cursor.NodeItem$NodeItemHelper.getRelationships(NodeItem.java:81)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.OperationsFacade.nodeGetRelationships(OperationsFacade.java:319)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy$2.iterator(NodeProxy.java:201)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy$2.iterator(NodeProxy.java:193)
```

From the code:

```
Iterable<Relationship> rels = node.getRelationships( ... any various args ... );
for (Relationship rel : rels) {
    // Some computation
}
```

Comment: Yes this is annoying :( This has to do with nodes not being marked as sparsed. An issue was already opened on Github and I hope 2.3.1 will be released soon https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/5691

Comment: What does "sparsed" mean?

Comment: non-dense. Nodes are marked as dense after a certain treshold, and marked as parsed when relationships are deleted and the nodes become below the treshold, apparently this bug introduce the fact that the node was not re-marked as parse. More info in the fix here : https://github.com/tinwelint/neo4j/commit/32545fad727d2d8821b1b5522e5163952d7e3951

Comment: Thanks. BTW, if you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept. I don't see how it gets more accurate than "It's officially a bug."

Comment: That's why I wouldn't make an answer, it is officially a bug :)

Comment: Fine. Once 2.3.1 comes out, and it fixes it, I'll accept "You should upgrade." Meanwhile, I need to stay on RC1.